# Send msg.value to another address immediately

Tags: solidity, payable, transfer

Is it possible to implement a `payable` function and transfer `msg.value` to another address immediately?

```
function purchase() payable public {
  //transfer msg.value
}
```

I'm thinking this wouldn't work because the ether hasn't completely arrived in the smart contract yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nope, works just fine.  Smart contracts are pretty amazing

```
function purchase() payable public {
  owner.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the previous mentioned, this work just fine. Although you need to typecast the receiving address to be payable, since the addresses and functions expecting a payment should be marked payable.

```
function purchase() payable public {
  payable(receivingAddress).transfer(msg.value);
}
```